# How do I re-create "this" inside an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an event handler that was pre-bound to a specific variable (via `$.proxy`).  As a result, when the handler is triggered, `this` isn't the normal value, it's my pre-bound value.

I'd like to recover `this` using the handler's `event` argument, but `this` doesn't seem to map directly to `event.currentTarget`, `event.target`, or any other event property.

So, I've tried digging through the jQuery source, but the event callback stuff is very convoluted, and I can't figure out exactly what `this` is getting set to.  Does anyone know how simulate a jQuery event handler `this` using only the event argument?

*** * Edit * ***

Just to clarify, here's an example:

```
var boundThis = {foo: 'bar'}
var handler = $.proxy(function(event) {

    // Because of the $.proxy, this === boundThis
    // (NOT the normal "this" that jQuery would set)
    // In theory event has everything I need to re-create this,
    // but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how

    // Here's a naive/non-functional example of what I'm trying to do
    jQueryThis = event.target; // If only this worked ...

}, boundThis);
$(someElement).click(handler);
```

Comment: Done (although the question I'm asking is very generic, so sample code isn't too relevant; ANY passing of a $.proxy-ed function to ANY jQuery event hookup will demonstrate this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` is typically the value of `this` with jQuery events. As described [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/):

> ***Description**: The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.*

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rhgEB/.

While `event.target` remains as `#baz`, `event.currentTarget` references the current element being handled; same as `this` does without a `proxy`.

*** * Edit by machineghost * ***

Just to save future readers some time, the "magic formula" for generating a `this` equivalent based on an event object ("`e`") is:

```
var fakeThis = e.delegateTarget === e.currentTarget ? e.currentTarget : e.target;
```

Comment: Right, event.currentTarget is (something like) half the answer.  The other half is event.target (although I'm ignorant enough of all this that there might be a third piece).  Regardless, the tricky part is figuring out (from the event object) which one I want: it's not always currentTarget (or always target).

Comment: @machineghost `event.target` is the element that started the event, which doesn't change as the event bubbles. `event.currentTarget` is the element being handled currently and is the element the event was bound to (or matched to in the case of delegated events). Watch the log in the demo as the IDs either change or remain the same as the event bubbles through each `<div>`.

Comment: Right, but `this !== event.currentTarget` (or at least, not always).  I'll try to look at my code so I can explain examples of the cases that require one or the other (I would have done that already, but I honestly thought "what exactly is `this` set to in an event handler?" would be a well-known bit of info, so I didn't think it'd be necessary)

Comment: @machineghost From [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/): "*When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`.*"

Comment: Awesome; I did look through the `.on` docs, but somehow I missed that so thank you.  So now, we're almost there, except for one last thing: from the event object, how do I determine whether the event was directly bound or delegated (so that I can use `target` or `currentTarget`, as appropriate)?

Comment: @machineghost `currentTarget` should be what you want in either case. Still, you can use [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to determine "Delegated or Direct": `var isDelegated = event.delegateTarget !== event.currentTarget;`